# hide and show method with inappbrowser didn't work in phonegap application

Tags: android, ios, phonegap-plugins, show-hide, inappbrowser

I'am developing a phonegap application which is based on webview concept and i want to show and hide the window according to some uses of the client.. hide() and show() method didn't work on ios and android devices  despite the documentation of inappbrowser plugin is very clear and simple..
this is an example of code:

```
win = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://www.facebook.com/", "_blank","location=no,EnableViewPortScale=yes,toolbar=no" );
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("hide the window"); win.hide(); }, 10000);
        setTimeout(function(){ alert("show the window"); win.show(); }, 20000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed this doesn't work on iOS (PG 7.0.1, cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1). Seems to be a bug, you can log an issue the [Apache Cordova Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=190&projectKey=CB).

Comment: i think you are right this is the problem..did you find another solution for that? i logged the issue and i wait for response..

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the `close` method?

Comment: because i have some session data that i shouldn't lose..also i can't return exactly to the right location if i close the window..

Comment: Fair enough. obly other option I can think of. Have to wait for the bug fix then I guess.